# IBM MQ: AMQ7026E: A principal or group name was invalid

Tags: ibm-mq

I am getting below error when I am executing `setmqaut` on IBM-MQ queue manager

```
bash-4.4$ setmqaut -m QM1 -t qmgr -p mqadmin +connect
AMQ7026E: A principal or group name was invalid.
```

Comment: That means that there is not a user called mqadmin defined.   Where the user needs to be defined depends on how you have MQ configured, for example by default MQ will look to the OS for the user but can also be configured to use LDAP.  In newer versions of MQ there is an option to not check for the user which can be used if you never need to provide password authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error basically returns that MQ was not able to find user 'mqadmin'. Please check the queue manager CONNAUTH value for the configured authentication method. If the default 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS' is used then check within the machine to see if the user 'mqadmin' is available. If you are using LDAP for authentication then check if that 'mqadmin' is available on ldap server and MQ is able to contact ldap server.